# How to configure Dovecot to not serve large emails to high-latency clients?

Tags: email, imap, dovecot

I have a Dovecot mailserver running at home on a flaky cable connection.  For the most part, the IMAP functionality works beautifully, but I'd like to add one feature if I can: I want Dovecot *not* to serve large messages to high-latency clients.  That is to say, if someone decides that it's a good idea to send me a 9.3mb email to me, I don't want to get it unless I'm on my LAN at home.

This can't be an uncommon request, but I'm having trouble finding the configuration option in their documentation.  Any ideas and/or good keywords to use in Googling would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt this is possible with any IMAP server. After all, why would  you want to let the server decide which mail to see and what metric should it use to decide this?

The best spot to configure this in your mail client: Tell it to just download the headers and the mail body only on request. Fast, simple and reliable.

Comment: Hmm.  Well if that's the case, can you recommend a good Linux IMAP client?  'Cause Kmail doesn't seem to have those controls.

Comment: Looks like the problem wasn't that Kmail didn't have the option to limit file size, but rather the defaults were to download only the headers, but a filter I had in place required that it download the whole message body to test if the filter should be applied.  My bad.  Thanks for your patience :-)